# PowerBI - Referencing a previous/next row to calculate derivitaves (calculus)

Tags: powerbi, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to create a column that applies numerical differentiation and integration on another column but do not know how to reference a previous row.

My example data has columns:  **x | y | y'**

A formula for differentiation is :

```
y' = y(x+h)-y(x-h) / 2h
```

In excel, this is really easy.

```
C3 = (B4-B2)/2*(A3-A2)
```

Here is an example of this code being executed in Excel:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnJYb.png)  The equation for y:  y = 0.1*x^3 + x^2

However, in PowerBI i have no idea how to actually call a previous or next row's value.

I merely wish to calculate the y' column that formula.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access previous row because PowerBi has no concept of a row :).

There is only concept called [row context](https://powerbidatamodel.com/powerbi/what-is-row-context/), which you might leverage to achieve what you want with [earlier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/earlier-function-dax) function.

But you have to have some kind of unique "row identifier" (index column might do).

Please, provide sample data, so we can help you further.

Comment: As noted in the answer, u have to create unique row identifier. CHeck https://yodalearning.com/tutorials/learn-how-create-index-columns-using-power-query/ for example.

Then you can create new column, which contains "previous row" like this:

previour_row_kindof = 

var index = 'Table'[index]
return
CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK('Table'[column],1),ALL('Table'), 'Table'[index] < index)

After that, you perform your calculations